fix hair object position on flower
I'm trying to make a Bog Labrador Tea flower and I don't know how to make it stick out of the target mesh with the angle of the face it's being placed on, also as a bonus I would appreciate if someone also knows how to have it evenly separated

hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/
